# Laravel-mix adding and compiling new js

Tags: laravel, compilation, laravel-mix

I am a beginner to this framework. i have added new css files in my sass folder and compiled them successfully to use.

How can i add new js file in assets folder and compile them to use ?

Comment: You can just add them directly in the assets folder and target them using the <script src="gotoassets/custom.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You can do somethink like this but before stop npm compiling:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/frontend/js/scripts.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/frontend/scss/style.scss', 'public/css');
```

And then run just `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`.

Comment: i do not have a default "Frontend" named folder... can i place this file in "assets/js" folder and then compile ? ... why is the need of external folder..

Comment: @LaviJ i did it for myself. You can just add another.js to same folder where app.js located.

Answer (score 1):

i concluded some things as a beginner:
1. we put our js or css files in assets/css, assets/js folder and using webpack.min.js we compile this files and minimize.
2. after compilation, the compiled code generates in public/css,  public/js folders accordingly.
3. My js file has some external links and things as i am using a theme for a blog, and it is getting issues in compilation.
4. the solution is to put your files directly in public/js or public/css folders .

If anyone has any further suggession... please share.

Thanks